# Removing an adBannerView in Swift (SpriteKit)

Tags: swift, view, iad

When the user crashes and the game over code block is run the `adBannerView` appear at the top of the screen, when the user taps to play again it dissapears using the `removeFromSuperView()`

However, if the user goes to the "Settings Scene" (ad banner view dissapears and when the settings scene loads it loads a new bannerView ect) but when i hit the "Play" Button (which takes the user back to the `gameScene` the adBannerview doesn't get removed

In my game Scene:

```
 override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    /* Setup your scene here */

    adBannerView.removeFromSuperview()
 }

 contactBegins {
 //GameOver
 loadAds()
 }

// Pressed Settings Node 
adBannerView.removeFromSuperview()
```

In settings i have exactly the same setup then when the user presses "Play" it has `removeFromSuperView` but nothing gets removed when it transitions to the next scene...

Answer (score 0):

When your move to the next scene just make the banner hidden like this:

```
adBannerView.hidden = true
```

Also, look through your code and make sure you're not re-adding the banner in the game scene as that could be the problem too.